# Configuring Exclusive Free Trial Period for iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit2

I am currently working on an iOS application using StoreKit2 and I have encountered a challenge related to In-App Purchases (IAP). Specifically, I have two products, namely **com.myProduct.monthly** and **com.myProduct.yearly**, both of which have been configured with a free trial period of one month.

However, my requirement is to allow users to utilize the trial period for only one product, either the monthly or the yearly subscription, but not for both concurrently. The current setup provides a trial period of one month for both products.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to achieve this exclusivity in the free trial period for the mentioned products.

Comment: Did you put both subscriptions in the same subscription group? https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/set-up-introductory-offers-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I got my answer from the Apple document you provided the link. <3 You saved my time.